# I can't imort pyPDF2 module in python

Tags: python, module

I have installed pyPDF2 module using **pip install pyPDF2** command in it is successfully installed. But when I import pyPDF2 module i get error no module named pyPDF2

Comment: What operating system do you use? What python version do you use?
If you use python3: Try to install the module with pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: i also tried that but having same error and I am using python3 in window 10

Comment: You can create an environment with pip and within that environment try it again.
An alternative to pip is conda btw.
I suspect your python to be the wrong one. You might have "multiple pythons" on your system and probably you are using the one that is not able to get the pip modules.

Comment: I'm using python pip module and created a game in python. It is only having error in pyPDF2 module. But I if you say i will uninstall python and reinstall it

Comment: Check first if the answer from ghchoi helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your `pip` is not for your `python`. Check if

```
which pip
which python
```

show the same parent directory.

If they don't you should use another `pip` inside `bin` of `which python`. Or, the following

```
python -m pip install
```

may use the proper `pip` for your `python`.

Comment: @RanjanaDadhich `which pip` and `which python` show the same path to `bin`?

Comment: not working showing "'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." it can be my mistake but i started python just week ago

Comment: @RanjanaDadhich You can still find the path to Python installed.